# How do I remove “Uncategorized” from my theme on my posts page?

Tags: categories, themes

[image: My posts page with “Uncategorized” at the bottom]

How would I remove “Uncategorized” on my posts page and replace it with some of the other topics I discuss on my blog? I use the “Calm Blog” theme from Craft Themes (wordpress.org).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go to Setting->Writing and change the Default Post Category to your preferred category. Then un-assign any posts that have it as uncategorized.

Comment: Absolutely bizarre that default post category is buried is hidden under Writing settings of all places, and I can't imagine how you found out it was, but thank you.